# Check if multiple rows are filled and if not blank all values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID  Name    Date    Code    Manager
1   Paulo   %   10  Jonh's Peter
2   Pedro   2001-01-20  20  
3   James       30  
4   Sofia   2001-01-20  40  -
```

I need a way to check if multiple columns (in this case Date, Code and Manager) are filled with any value. In the case there is any blank in any of those 3 columns, blank all the values in all 3 columns, returning this data:

```
ID  Name    Date    Code    Manager
1   Paulo   %   10  Jonh's Peter
2   Pedro           
3   James           
4   Sofia   2001-01-20  40  -
```

What is the best solution for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.isnull()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html) with [`pandas.any(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) then use [`pandas.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for setting what value that you want.

```
col_chk = ['Date', 'Code', 'Manager']
m = df[col_chk].isnull().any(axis=1)
df.loc[m , col_chk] = '' # or pd.NA
print(df)
```

---

```
   ID   Name        Date  Code       Manager
0   1  Paulo           %  10.0  Jonh's Peter
1   2  Pedro                                
2   3  James                                
3   4  Sofia  2001-01-20  40.0             -
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.loc`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to replace values in certain colums and based on a condition .

Considering that your dataframe is named `df`:

[image]

You can use this code to get the expected output :

```
df.loc[df[["Date", "Code", "Manager"]].isna().any(axis=1), ["Date", "Code", "Manager"]] = ''
```

##### `>>> print(df)`

[image]

Comment: from question : **there is any blank in any of those 3 columns,** not only `Manager`

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how to fix my code so it can check three columns instead of one ? You can directly edit my answer, if you want !

Comment: You're welcome. You can use `any(axis=1)` like this : `df.loc[df[["Date", "Code", "Manager"]].isna().any(axis=1), ["Date", "Code", "Manager"]] = ''`